# What does soundness of a semantic reasoner mean?

Tags: logic, semantics, semantic-web

Many articles about semantic reasoner, refer to soundness as a characteristic of the reasoner or a reasoning algorithm. 
However from definition of soundness from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) I understand that soundness is a property of my model and independent from reasoning algorithm that I apply to it. 
For example the model:

```
All organisms with wings can fly. 
Penguins have wings.
```

Leads to the following valid (provable?) but unsound result:

```
Penguins can fly.
```

So when I give this model to a for example Tableaux-based algorithm, or the KAON2 reasoner, that are both said to be sound, they would still give me this unsound result. 
So can you please describe to me what is the soundness exactly? and if it is a characteristic of model or modeling language or reasoning method or just the inference result?

Comment: It's not sound because it's written. If you read it out loud, it'll be sound.

Comment: Do all organisms with wings fly? that doesnt sound sound to me..

Comment: Yes, “soundness” is used to described a reasoning algorithm. A model is a mapping from sentences to truth values. “All organisms with wings can fly. Penguins have wings.” does not look like a model to me.

Comment: @nawfal Yes, this also my point. Here the model is not sound. So soundness should be a characteristic of a model, not the modeling language or reasoning algorithm. So why it is being said that Tableaux algorithm or KAON2 reasoner are sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means correct.  Sound means the reasoner will return only correct results, that is, results that are either explicit in the knowledge base, or entailed from its contents.  Unsound would mean that the reasoner returns a result that is both not explicit in your KB, and not entailed by any axiom(s), ie, an incorrect result.

Complete means it returns *all* the answers.  You can be sound without being complete, that is, returning a subset of all correct answers.  This can be desirable in some use cases.

You can also be complete, but unsound; you return all the correct answers, and some incorrect ones as well.

In your example, the result is only unsound to you because you have information that the KB does not, namely, that penguins cannot fly.  From the reasoner's point of view, that's a sound result.  It cannot confirm the veracity of the facts it's given, it just uses them to entail new ones.

Comment: Thank you. I think this basically answers my question. The soundness of a reasoner means that it does not return incorrect results, i.e. results that are not explicitly in the KB or can be entailed from its axioms. So the soundness can be a characteristic of model, inference result, and reasoner. It depends from which point of view you look at it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is valid, but one of the premises is not true.  Therefore the argument is not sound.

I don't think the reasoner can decide if your premises are true - if it could, then that would be quite revolutionary :)

Comment: What does this mean: "... Most of the underlying reasoning methodologies have been proven to be sound and complete. The tableaux and hypertableaux calculi are sound and complete....". As just an example taken from here [http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/sites/default/files/swj120_2.pdf](http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/sites/default/files/swj120_2.pdf)

Comment: @zardosht - I would suppose that to mean that the algorithms themselves consist of only sound reasoning.  That is that they are "provably correct".